# Updating app or just the Database in Vuforia or in AR Foundation (unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, ar-foundation

I have three markers (image targets) and i want every week to show different AR content for each target. Is that possible to accomplish it without updating the app in play and app store every week? I am asking either with using Vuforia or AR Foundation.

I tried it on AR Foundation and Vuforia and of course it does not work because i have, somehow, to register the new content. I am wondering if there is a way to have the content on line in a specific place and every week to change this stuff....

Comment: This is probably possible with some Unity scripting. The app on startup should check for new content on some cloud location (may be use a CMS) and then replace the renderable asset in Unity. This is not something specific to an AR app. I would look for information from the unity developer community as it is very likely a common use case.